# How to run a .jar file in c#

Tags: c#, jar, process.start

How to run the file `C:/Myjarfile.jar` in C#? When I try `Process.Start("C:\\Myjarfile.jar")`, it says:

> ```
> file cannot be found
> ```

Comment: Why did you tag java?

Comment: `Process.Start("java -jar C:\\Myjarfile.jar")`?

Comment: @GenoChen still says file cannot be found

Comment: Is the file located in that location? Spelled correctly? Capitalized correctly? Is it accessible?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes

Comment: either java is not installed and / or your file isn't at the location you try to call it from

Comment: Do you have permission problem at C:\ Root directory ?

Comment: Can you run the file from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Java .jar files are not executeable for themself. Instead you have to run the JRE with the arguments `-jar <PathToYourJar>`. Under **most** systems the JRE can be started with the `java` command. So you need to write `Process.Start("java -jar <PathToYourJar>")`